# GoogleDrive Service listFiles() shared (closed)

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I have an issue, I am currently using apiDriveService from Google's own API. I am getting a list of files, which works fine using

```
$result = $drive->files->listFiles();
```

Is there a way to know with whom the files are shared.. Let me explain myself better.. I create a document on Google Drive and share it with my boss for example, I would like to see with whom that file is shared.

Is this possible?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the permissions of those files using the [permissions collection](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list) for a file. However, the file will only contain an ID for each user and not the email address. This is so that other people with read permission will not be able to sniff the email addresses of other viewers, thereby circumventing privacy measures.

Comment: Great ! Never thought of that ! Cheers :)